# Dynamic row length in a QGridLayout

Tags: qt, layout, pyside

I'm looking to make an image viewer using PySide and Qt, where all the images are of fixed size and arranged in a grid. I know how to set up the basic code for this by defining a `QGridLayout` such as this:

```
l = QGridLayout(10,10)
l.addItem(im1,0,0)
l.addItem(im2,0,1)
...
```

However, I also want the number of elements per row to resize dynamically. I will know in advance how many images there are, but I won't know how big the dialog will be. So if the user makes the dialog very small, there should be 2 images per line, but if they maximize it, there should be (e.g.) 10 images per line. Is there a way to make a `QGridLayout` that adjusts the row size dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `QGridLayout` for this purpose, use `FlowLayout` instead. FlowLayout is not a built-in layout in Qt but it is developed by someone else, you can use it by just copying `FlowLayout` class to your project file. [this](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py) is the example of `FlowLayout`. Copy the whole code to your IDE and run it (remember to change the import statements at the top to PySide as that code is using PyQt4). After executing the code, resize the window that appears, you will see that the pushButtons inside the window will be adjusted automatically.